# Get last access time of any app in Android

Tags: android

> How do I find the last time when any application was used in Android. Which means last >access time for any app?

Comment: I am not aware that this information is recorded anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self:

```
IUsageStats mUsageStatsService = IUsageStats.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("usagestats"));
PkgUsageStats[] stats = mUsageStatsService.getAllPkgUsageStats();
```

Pull out the map from the desired array index. This map contains the last time the app was accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the Calendar class to save an instance when the onCreate or onDestroy executes for your app. You could then save the time into a private app file using a OutputStreamWriter and just read it's contents using an InputStreamWriter whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

As i know there are no instances which records this. You can easily make it yourself by adding a Database and Record every Start with timestamp or calender instances. Then you `COUNT(*)` it and there you go.